# Vários submits em um form

Tags: javascript, post, formulário-submeter

Tenho um botão "Exportar" que envia os dados do formulário via Post. Preciso que o esses dados possam ser enviados várias vezes sem atualizar a página, mas o navegador está bloqueando mais de um "Submit" desse formulário.
Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Quando você dá submit o navegador irá redirecionar para a localização destino e ao voltar, o formulário aparece apagado de novo. O que você precisar é de um botão que _simule_ o submit e faça o envio dos campos via **Ajax**, de preferência por meio do uso de **JQuery**.

Comment: Via ajax não irá funcionar no meu caso...

Comment: Me permita discordar, creio que funcionaria. Mas se você não quer usar Ajax, vai precisar submeter realmente a página e recarregá-la após isso. O que se pode fazer então é aproveitar os dados que você já enviou e retornar a página com os inputs já preenchidos com os últimos valores enviados. Ou seja, a página "envia os dados para ela mesma", salvando a cada envio, permitindo assim você mudar apenas o necessário na próxima submissão.